# Running chef-analytics with Chef Server 12 RC2

Tags: chef-infra

I have setup the Chef Server 12 RC2 on my Redhat 6.2 system. I have also installed Opscode-analytics(in combined mode) package according to the documentation provided [here](http://docs.getchef.com/install_analytics.html).

The package gets downloaded accordingly, and reconfigure also returns success. But when I run the test command to see, it returns with the following error :

```
ERROR: Chef Actions not running at 'https://chefserver12-analytics.com/'
```

Following are the relevant contents of configuration files :

```
/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb :

opscode_webui['enable']=false
api_fqdn = 'https://10.98.241.119'
dark_launch['actions'] = true

/etc/opscode-analytics/ opscode-analytics.rb :

analytics_fqdn "chefserver12-analytics.com"
```

I have hit a dead end with the search. Please help.
As per coderanger's suggestion, I created a private-chef.rb file with the relevant configuration settings. Now the opscode-analytics-ctl tail command seems to work, but I still cannot access the UI on `https://chefserver12-analytics.com`. I have attached a link to the output of the command.

> http://pastebin.com/QU3f5J7P

Answer (score 0):

For the moment the RC builds have their config file at `/etc/opscode/private-chef.rb`. This is a holdover from the private chef days, and should change before final release I think.

Comment: Yup. Created this file and the analytics funtionality is working now, but I don't get how to access the UI for analytics. I have updated the ques with a screenshot of the output, I get after running the tail command on opscode-analytics.